# javascript variable not works in Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization, highcharts

```
  chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container3',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Cumplimiento de los Programas del PMA-Contratistas'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        'Nº Charlas ambientales',
                        'Nº personal capacitado'

                    ]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: '%'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 100,
                    y: 70,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return ''+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{name: 'Semana',data: [12   , 321]  }, {name: 'Acum',data: [85, 65]}]
            });
```

this is my Highchart code

when I am using javascript variable

like this

```
  g311 = $("#g311").val();
        g312 = $("#g312").val();
        g321 = $("#g321").val();
        g322 = $("#g322").val();
```

and pass this in series

```
   series: [{name: 'Semana',data: [g311, g312]  }, {name: 'Acum',data: [g321, g322]}]
```

it is not showing me graph please give me some way how to pass jquery variable in series (not static or PHP variable)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As long as you do your `g311 = ...` lines **before** your `new Highcharts.Chart` line, and as long as the elements you're referring to exist as of when you do your `g311 = $("#g311")` and similar, **and** if those are inputs with values in them, it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me you need to convert them to numbers first *because input elems have values as strings*:

```
g311 = +$("#g311").val();
g312 = +$("#g312").val();
g321 = +$("#g321").val();
g322 = +$("#g322").val();
```

and **you need to declare these above the chart**.

prefixing `+` converts a string to number.

Comment: Thanks @jai .....you actually understood my problem seems like you have faced this one :D  Bless You Thanks

Comment: you can also use parseFloat() function.